Customized Verbatim environment with line breaking and hyphenation
I want a custom verbatim environment that has the following:

It ignores code inside the enviroment (i.e. behave like verbatim usually does).
The contents are justified.
Relatedly, it breaks lines (including inside words, if necessary), and adds a hyphen when breaking up words.
It doesn't add any other symbols (such as "↵") when breaking up lines.
Custom background color (negotiable).
XeTeX compatible (negotiable).

Hyphenation is the one I'm stumbling on. Happy to use either fvextra or tcolorbox, but haven't been able to turn on hyphenation with either of them. Here's what I have so far:
%! TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbBreakAnywhereBreak}{\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines=true,breakanywhere=true,breaksymbolleft={}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et ullamcorper libero, eget rutrum enim. Proin vitae volutpat nisl. Nulla at mauris dictum, interdum sapien nec, mollis diam. Sed at lacus consequat, consectetur odio ac, iaculis urna. Phasellus risus nisi, euismod at vehicula vitae, gravida sit amet eros. Phasellus feugiat sapien eleifend dui elementum, eleifend finibus nunc efficitur. Phasellus maximus, sem a vehicula congue, nisi sem bibendum massa, elementum sollicitudin magna turpis rutrum lorem. Nullam nec venenatis lacus. Vivamus accumsan mauris ac enim gravida, quis suscipit quam aliquet. Cras nec neque posuere, tincidunt risus vitae, egestas eros. In faucibus arcu ac enim vehicula, a ullamcorper enim vulputate.

Nunc faucibus, nibh nec condimentum posuere, tellus mauris tempus urna, eu vestibulum mi mi vel justo. Proin eget luctus lacus. Integer rutrum metus lorem, eget varius augue tristique at. Etiam vel lacus pellentesque, scelerisque ex pellentesque, vulputate tellus. Nulla facilisi. Nam ultricies dolor in pellentesque lacinia. Sed iaculis accumsan volutpat. Maecenas placerat, dui at fermentum eleifend, erat orci consequat massa, vitae consequat purus orci consequat risus. Mauris euismod libero vitae finibus lobortis. Etiam consectetur magna eget sagittis porttitor.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}

Which gives:


Could you explain a bit what the goal is? Usually when there is any kind of code within a piece of text then that means that it is not actually text, which means that you should not hyphenate because that changes the content of the original source. However, if it is real text that just has some special characters like { and } at some places then you could consider either escaping those or changing the way they are interpreted, and not using any type of verbatim environment at all. So, what is the use case? Maybe you can give a real example instead of lipsum?

Good point. I'm planning to use this to answer questions and submissions from students. These comments will be mostly in English but may also contain code in various programming languages (including latex), and I want an environment that deals with the general case while looking pretty.

I guess in that case using normal text with \verb or \lstinline or \mintinline for the code would be the easiest - especially if you are writing the input yourself then you can add some formatting commands like these when needed. If you want an even simpler syntax then you could use for example the markdown package to indicate code fragments with single backticks.
